# 1-way anova in R help

Tags: r, anova

I am new in R (statistic packet) programming and I would like to make an 1way anova.

My frame of data is like that

```
     q1 sex
1    N   M
2    Y   F
3    U   F
   ...
1000 Y   M
```

Could you help me please ?

Comment: But you do not have a continuous variable to be used as an outcome???

Comment: Could you give a bit more information? Did you manage to import your data and get it as a data.fram in R? If so, could you just give us the output of `head(yourdataframe)` and `str(yourdataframe)`?

Comment: Just curious, could one map the alphabet in lexographic order, and M/F to 1/2 in order to do this?  Or does that not apply because `q1` is not necessarily related in that order?  Maybe you would analyze the M/F variance for each `q1` value, and then combine it into a chi-square distribution?

Comment: A cite from wikipedia: "In statistics, one-way analysis of variance (abbreviated one-way ANOVA) is a technique used to compare means of two or more samples (using the F distribution). This technique can be used only for numerical data[1]." You only have factorial data. Is there any numerical relation between you data? If so you can fit on this. But be careful not to introduce some meaningless scale as the lexicographic order - there is nothing that guarantees you that the distance between `N` and `M` is the same as between `M` and `Q`.

Answer (score 2):

Following up on @Thilo's and @DWin's comments above: if you really want to analyze the relationship between two categorical variables, you might try something like this:

```
## make up random data (no real pattern)
dat <- data.frame(q1=sample(c("N","Y","U"),size=1000,replace=TRUE),
                  sex=sample(c("M","F"),size=1000,replace=TRUE))
dtab <- with(dat,table(q1,sex))
chisq.test(dtab)
mosaicplot(dtab)
```

It would be really helpful from the point of view of answering your questions to have some more context: what question are you trying to answer?  Also, as always, it's nice to have a reproducible example (just to save the time of coming up with my own way of generating some fake data to play with).

One small point is that the Pearson chi-square test is testing for association; it doesn't distinguish between response and predictor variables as the ANOVA framework does.

Of course, if you really have a continuous response variable that you're neglecting to tell us about, then this won't be too useful ...